# How can I assign a static public ip to a machine behind a router?

Tags: routing, ipv4

I know about port-forwarding, but I'm interested in how to make a machine on a local network available to the public internet without port-forwarding.

Comment: That depends on the network topology and the network device models.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Port forwarding aka reverse NAT aka destination NAT is generally required when you want to allow a public IPv4 client access to a server with a private IPv4 address.

An alternative is a proxy with a public IP address doing the translation. Proxies are off-topic here due to them working on the application layer.

You can go without translation only when the server already has a public IP address. For that you need to have your ISP route more than one IP address for you. For IPv6 that is the rule, so it doesn't require translation generally.

Comment: If the server has a public ipv4 address, is it also the local address of the server?

Comment: A host may have multiple IP addresses, on different interfaces or even on a single one. So, it might have a private *and* a public address.

Comment: How can a single interface have multiple IP addresses? What is the rule that determine which IP will be the source IP of the outgoing IP packets?

Comment: An interface can have as many IP addresses as the system/OS supports. Multiple addresses might not be too common for IPv4 but it's the rule for IPv6. The outgoing IP is determined by the local routing table.

Answer (score 0):

How to make a machine on a local network available to the public internet without port-forwarding:

The above requirement is feasible by natting one  static public IP provided by ISP to local server private ip address and ensure inbound policy is configured in perimeter firewall as ..

**If router is perimeter device**

```
Ip nat inside souce static "private ip address' public ip address"
```

**If firewall is perimeter device**

```
Source interfàce : egress interfàce
Destination interfàce : ingress interface
Source ip address :ANY
Destination ip address : natted public ip address
Services : specific port
Action: allow
```